# source file fixed width , need only Header and Footer to the target(oracle)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have this scenario with source as fix width flat file, and I need to read to target only the Header and Footer not the details records.
I need to trim the first column (PA22109  ) and get only PA and next 2 columns to rows as two different dates.
For Footer get only the PT(PT000000000700000030620E00000055612I00000010277I) and the rest into a column of the target.
 How can I achieve this logic, inputs are appreciated.

source file :

PA22109                     00153252015110905408179                    2015110820151108PO  ---header

DE0E9D                    TESTGROUPEXCH        TESTINSEXCH         TESTLOCEXCH                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ID014               LNAME014                           FNAME014                            14 MAIN ST                                                                                                    ANYWHERE                      NJ011110000      195001012Z 01000000014           LNAME014                           PATFIRST014                         14 MAIN ST                                                                                                    ANYWHERE                      NJ011110000      1955010110106000220          TESTGROUPEXCH  8179     TESTBENEXCH    TESTCNTE53   0000000000 0000002643005     011234567890     011234567890     1234   TEST PHARMACY                      TEST PHARMACY LANE                                                                                            PHARMACYTOWN                  NJ09876             5555555555   11Y5         019876543210     019876543210               NJPRESCLAST                          PRESCFIRST               5555555551                 DRLAST                             DRFIRST                  110110000009770990300406048410        2015092720150927154401000000000000120150929  0000100000000000000000000000000

PT000000000700000030620E00000055612I00000010277I  --Footer

Comment: Use a command task to do a `head` and `tail` to a separate file and load it?

Comment: samik, nothing was clicking in my mind how to start, any inputs are apperciated.

Answer (score 1):

As this a fixed file you can perform following to meet your requirement.

1. In your Informatica mapping, Read row in a single column.
2. In Expression, Mark each record for filter out if It does not start with PA OR PT (Assumption your Detail records do not start with PA or PT). Filter detail record out using Filter transformation.
3. Now you have only Header and Footer Records.
4. Now you can apply respective condition in expression for PA and PT Records.

Comment: Thanks for your input vivek, but i had a question of how do we split the row level to column level as my target is a oracle table.do i need to use any normalizer??

Comment: Perhaps i couldn't get your requirement properly. For Header Logic, You want PA along with two dates like given - PA  DATE1  DATE2. I mean do you want three columns ?? Could you get me some sample output data ??

Comment: Vivek, there is a slight change in the requirement .